# Regex to get letters in between two angle brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for regex that will get all alphabetical letters (a-zA-Z) between `<` and `>`
I dont know regex well at all but i had this `\<:([a-zA-Z]+)\>` and it wasnt working

Here is an example of what I want to happen:

becomes
text

thank you!

Comment: ... are you trying to use Regex to parse HTML... ? ... oh no

Answer (score 1):

<[a-zA-Z]+>

is probably what you're looking for

```js
document.getElementById('inp').addEventListener("keyup",check);
function check(e){
  const regex = /<[a-zA-Z]+>/g;
  while ((m = regex.exec(e.target.value)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = match;
    });
}
}
```

```html
<input id='inp'/> Type a tag in here
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<[a-zA-Z]+>`.

Some explanation:

1. `[a-zA-Z]` - match any character from a-z or A-Z (lower or capital case).
2. `+` - match one or more characters of what comes before `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question misses some details. Here is an answer making these assumptions:

- you have a string with text that has `<xyz>` patterns, where `xyz` has 1+ alpha chars
- the string may have multiple `<xyz>` patterns
- return value is an array of patterns found, empty if none

Further, it is not clear if you need to extract the alpha chars with or without angle brackets, so here is an answer that shows both:

```js
const regex1 = /<[a-zA-Z]+>/g;
const regex2 = /(?<=<)[a-zA-Z]+(?=>)/g;
[
  '<a>', '<hr>', 'foo <div> bar', 'foo <br> bar <br> moo', // matches
  '</nothing>', 'no tag'                                   // no matches
].forEach(str => {
  let matches1 = str.match(regex1) || [];
  let matches2 = str.match(regex2) || [];
  console.log(str +
    ' => regex1: ' + JSON.stringify(matches1) +
    ' => regex2: ' + JSON.stringify(matches2));
});
```

Explanation of regex1:

- `<` -- angle bracket
- `[a-zA-Z]+` -- character class with 1+ alpha chars
- `>` -- angle bracket

Explanation of regex2:

- `(?<=<)` -- positive lookbehind for an angle bracket
- `[a-zA-Z]+` -- character class with 1+ alpha chars
- `(?=>)` -- positive lookahead for an angle bracket

Please note that not all browsers support lookbehind, notably Safari.

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex